# NVM not installing on Ubuntu 21.04 Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, nvm

I've been having issues with upgrading my version of Node.js recently and one of the ways I've tried was with node version manager. When I install the `install_nvm.sh` file with `curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh` and ran `bash install_nvm.sh`, I get this error:

```
install_nvm.sh: line 1: 400: : command not found
```

My version of Node is on 12.21.0 and NPM is on 7.18.1. This started when I tried to download a dependency called `"yt-search"`, but it said that it depended on a vulnerable version of `"cheerio"`, `"css-select"` and `"css-what"`. I tried to install each of them one by one to their recent versions, but the error still was there. I had to reinstall my terminal over 10 times to attempt to fix this because when I went further, the errors started to pile up.

[image: When I tried to install yt-search with npm]

Comment: Note that upgrading `yt-search` to 2.9.0 fixes this vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that version came out recently lol

Answer (score 0):

Like what [frozen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6702495/frozen) said in the comments, upgrading it to 2.9.0 solved the issues!